# Filtrar un conjunto de datos usando un array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo la siguiente consulta la cual me da el resultado que quiero

```
$this->categoryareas = categoryarea::where('id_category', "=", 35)
        ->get();

$this->select = $this->categoryareas->pluck('id_area');

**Obtengo lo siguiente : [9,3,7]**
```

para la siguiente consulta

```
$this->categoryareass = area::where('id', "!=",  [$this->select])->get();
```

y estoy obteniendo este resultado

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Admin y Personas","code":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":2,"name":"Hseq","code":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":3,"name":"Contabilidad","code":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":4,"name":"Tesoreria","code":4,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":5,"name":"Contratos","code":5,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":6,"name":"Selecci\u00f3n","code":6,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":7,"name":"Sistemas","code":7,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},
{"id":8,"name":"Desarrollo de Negocios","code":8,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

y me esta ignorando

```
{"id":9,"name":"Area prueba","code":34,"created_at":"2021-07-09T00:11:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-09T00:11:26.000000Z"}
```

pero no me esta ignorando el [3,7], no me esta pasando la array completa solo el primer valor que es el [9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la pude solucionar el incoveniente de la siguiente manera

```
$this->categoryareass = area::whereNotIn('id', $this->select)->get();
```

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/282947)

Comment: pero si esta es la respuesta a lo que estaba buscando? no entiendo el comentario.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres obtener todas las áreas cuyo id no esté entre los valores del array en `$this->select`, entonces lo que debes emplear sería el método [`whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) de la siguiente forma:

```
$this->categoryareass = area::whereNotIn('id', $this->select)->get();
```

El detalle con tu consulta actual es que si obtenemos el string sql sería algo como esto:

```
SELECT * FROM area WHERE id != [............];
```

Mientras que con la query propuesta sería algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM area WHERE id NOT IN (.............);
```